# In VS Code, how can I choose which source control provider is used for diff decorations?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

In Visual Studio Code, like many modern IDEs, changes from source control are shown in the editor with different highlight colors denoting changed/added/deleted lines.

However, if there are several source control repositories set up for one folder, seemingly one is chosen to display these changes. Is it possible to manually set which repository should be used for showing the changes?

In this example image, there are two repositories in the list. Only the first repository is used to show the changes next to the line numbers, and selecting the other repository in the list doesn't change which lines are highlighted, despite the changes being different.

Is there a feature which allows to select this?

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio Code, with "source control repositories" and line numbers/highlights shown]

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple repositories"? you mean you have multiple remotes with branches for the same code?

Comment: There are multiple source control providers in the same project, for organizational reasons beyond my control. So the same project is set up to use a Perforce depot, and a Git repository, for the same code base. VS Code allows this with no issue, but the highlighting uses only the Git repo if one is present, despite the Perforce chagnes being supported: in projects that use only Perforce, and don't have Git set up, the highlighting correctly shows differences with the Perforce depot.

Answer (score 0):

The diff decorations are just shown relative to the current branch / whatever [HEAD](/q/2304087) is pointing to, no? (at least- that has been my understanding) So to get diff decorations against a different remote, you'd need to actually checkout the commit-ish/branch that you want the diff decorations to be comparing the working tree against.

If you have multiple source control providers in the same workspace, then you'll probably be interested in this issue ticket: [SCM: Gutter diff provider selection when multiple providers available #196759](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196759). Show your support for it by giving it a thumbs up. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

Also potentially related (I'm really not sure) is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.scmSelectedProvider.d.ts.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues diff decorations when multiple source control providers`".

Comment: That is indeed the case if only using one Source Control provider (i.e. just Git). In cases like mine, where there are more than one (for example Git+SVN, which is admittedly quite an edge case), there doesn't seem to be an option to choose which one is used for the decorations.

Comment: @goose_lake please see edit.

Comment: Ah thanks! Good to know there are other people interested in the feature. Will give it a thumbs up.